# Multiple drag and drop file input - add next file and max file limit

Tags: java, javascript, jquery, file, input

This is my drag and drop field:

```
<div style="margin-bottom: 1em;">
    <div class="file-well">
        <input type="file" name="file" id="file" multiple/>
        <span id="filewelllabel">click here or drag and drop to add<br/></span>
        <span id="filewelllabel">you can add up to 5 files (.pdf, .doc, .docx, .docm)</span>
    </div>
</div>
<p0></p0>
<%-- file names --%>
    <p1></p1>
    <p2></p2>
    <p3></p3>
    <p4></p4>
```

My limitation at this moment is:

```
$('#file').change(function() {
    var $fileUpload = $("input[type='file']");
    if (parseInt($fileUpload.get(0).files.length) > 5) {
        alert("max 5 files!");
        // this.files.length = 0;
        return false;
    }
    for (var i = 0; i < this.files.length; i++) {
        var filename = this.files[i].name.split('\\').pop();
        $("p" + i).html("choosen file: " + filename);

    }
});
```

But at this moment if I want multiple files I have drag and drop all of them at once. Otherwise they are replaced by new file I choose.

I want to be able to choose them one by one and display one just after its added, then if someone decide to add next I want it to be added as another file, not override existing.

How to do this?

Also how can I implement delete file option?

Answer (score 0):

please make following change-

```
var $fileUpload = $("input[type='file']");
```

to-

```
var $fileUpload = $(this);
```